# SPsite returning access error for an url different than the called one

Tags: development, spsite

I wrote a small C# .Net 4.5.2 application to rename some doc libraries.
It fails at the very beginning:

```
using(SPSite sitecoll=new SPSite("http://192.168.0.14:8069"))
```

with the message

```
Web application at http://localhost cannot be found
```

- The same app in the dev server runs fine, but there sharepoint is
  mapped to http://localhost.
- The same commands issued via powershell
  run fine.
- Sharepoint is totally accessible both locally and remotely via VPN, and I'm running the
  application as a sharepoint/site administrator.
- I also tried using the machine name http://sharepoint:8069 and http://localhost:8069
- I get slightly different errors running from the dev machine, remotely via VPN, in this case the URL is reported correctly:

  The web application at http://192.168.0.14:8069 cannot be found

**UPDATE**
I even tried a non-existing name, http://foo:8069, and I get the same reply!
Any advice?
Thank you

Comment: are you tried to use server name instead IP ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

It was a matter of security and permissions: I solved by running the code with

```
var elevata = new SPSecurity.CodeToRunElevated(
               delegate () { myCode(); });
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(elevata);
```